# Access a variable in imported module in Python

Tags: python

I have three Python scripts: aaa.py, bbb.py and ccc.py.

bbb.py:

```
import aaa as a
```

ccc.py:

```
import bbb as b
```

Can I use variable `a` directly in ccc.py? Like `a.hello`?

Or can any one please tell me how to access it?

Comment: In cccp.py, it should be available as b.a.hello

Comment: To use it as `a`, just use this: `a = b.a` ;-)

Comment: You *can*, but I wouldn't call this good practice. Import what you need explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ansewr should be yes.

```
import bbb as b
hello = b.a.hello
```